Go GORM many2many join
I have a problem with GORM's mapping. When I try to access Users from the Group it creates a wierd query for me. And it does not know about the third table. but here is an image of the db:
Before I'll get to the problem here's my 2 model:
type User struct {
    ID   uint   `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name string
    // etc...
}

type Group struct {
    ID               uint       `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    IsPrivateMessage bool
    Users            []*User    `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;many2many:group_user"`
}

So when I run this query:
err := database.DB.Model(models.Group{}).
Joins("Users").
Where("groups.id = ? and Users.id = ?", groupID, u.ID).
Limit(1).
Count(&count).Error

GORM creates this SQL for me:
SELECT count(*) FROM `groups` LEFT JOIN `users` `Users` ON `groups`.`id` = `Users`.`group_id` AND `groups`.`user_id` = `Users`.`id` WHERE groups.id = '1' and Users.id = 1 LIMIT

I even tried adding this like before joining user: Joins("group_user") but it added the group_user as an alias for groups in the query. Any solution for this problem? I really found nothing about it. And thats pain in the a.. right now.
